# How do I install VisTablet PenPad on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04

I am trying to install a Vistablet Penpad on Ubuntu 14.04, Ive heard it has been done on 13.x. How do I do this? Thanks.

And Just for additional information: I can only left click and right click, not move the cursor around.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=879409

That is a link that shows a thread that looks like some of them got it working.

Comment: Better check its website for installation guide.

Comment: I can't find anything in their website.

Comment: Do you have a windows installer of vista let?

Comment: Yes. I do. I tried running the installer with Wine, it said it successfully installed, but it still wouldn't work. I can left/right "click" on it, but I can't move the cursor around.

Comment: If there is no Linux support, then you can do nothing.

Comment: Wait for a day or two. For a solution. May be anyone else could help.

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=879409 They look like they did it somehow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15996/discussion-between-user287210-and-dishank).

Answer (score 0):

I find that it works fairly well using the software mypaint `sudo apt-get install mypaint` I haven't figured anything else out, regarding the macro hot keys. I am getting touch sensitivity, and the right click left click actions. Sorry for the necromancy, but I just got this hardware myself.

My vistablet shows up as a waltop pointing device, and I have seen linux support for their products in the past. I got nothing for this device currently though.